# Call same ajax from different element clicks with different data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call the same ajax function from different elements with different data.

For eg: I've these two links

```
<a href="#!" id="link1" data-source="google">Google</a>
<a href="#!" id="link2" data-source="facebook">Facebook</a>
```

and an Ajax call  like:

```
$("#link1).click(function() {
   $.post(
    '/myphpscript/', 
        {
          data:$("#link1).attr('data-source')
        }, // any data you want to send to the script
        function (data) {  
        }
});
```

I know that I can call same ajax with different elements like this:

```
$('#link1, #link2').click(some_function);
```

But how do I select the `data` based on the clicking element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an instance of `this`, also, give your links a common class and use a simple selector:

```
$(".ajaxLinks").click(function() {
    $.post('/myphpscript/', { data:$(this).attr('data-source') }, function (data) {

    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, seems this would work. That was a silly question :)

Comment: As a side note, you could use `$(this).data('source')`